# Error with a xml view

Tags: android

I keep getting this error

```
07-14 23:53:03.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14995): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 23:53:03.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14995):     at com.fttech.organizeit.meeting_list$meetingHolder.populateFrom(meeting_list.java:110)
07-14 23:53:03.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14995):     at com.fttech.organizeit.meeting_list$meetingAdapter.bindView(meeting_list.java:82)
07-14 23:53:03.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14995):     at    android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
07-14 23:53:03.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14995):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
```

It works when i run it on a xlarg screen. but when i run it on a regular layout it keeps force closing at this line

```
meetingHolder(View row){
        mtitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mtitle);
        maddress = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
        Icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Micon);

    }
    void populateFrom(Cursor c, meetingHelper helper){
        mtitle.setText(helper.getMettingTitle(c));
        maddress.setText(helper.getAddress(c));

        if(helper.getType(c).equals("completed")){
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.completed);

        }
```

Here is my xml for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="4dip">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Micon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
        android:textColor="#15317E"
            android:id="@+id/mtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            />

            <TextView
            android:textColor="#15317E"
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:ellipsize="middle"/>




        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea why this has started happening all of a sudden but its very annoying.

```
}
public String getType(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(7));
}
```

Comment: Just updated it with the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try fill_parent instead of match_parent

Comment: in your xml file for all the view

Comment: does it work if you block  Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.completed);
this line

Comment: I blocked Icon.setImageResouce. It still gave me a error at the if(helper.getType(c) but it cant be a problem with the getType because it runs fine on my tablet with xlarge screen. everything is loaded fine. its something with the icon

Comment: you see there is an error here.helper.getType(c) which is accepting a Cursor as a parameter and supposed to return a string.Go to getType method and see where is the problem.Use try catch block to see the actual error instead of force close

Comment: I just posted my getType method at the top it just returns the row of the TYPE which is row 7 in my database

Comment: But i didn't see any query that fill the cursor.Where did your right the query?

Comment: You are sending a cursor and returning string from that cursor.If that cursor is filled with data then you can get directly.No need to call this getType method

Comment: I don't get what your saying... like if that's the case it would force close no matter what screen size.

Comment: Your are calling getType(c).If c is filled with data then without calling can't you get c.getString(7)

Comment: What? Okay so if getType (c) is filled with data...without calling what?

Comment: i meant if cursor c is filled with data then why call to getType.as get type give you its 7 th index value which you can get directly

Comment: like c.getString(7).equals("completed")

Comment: How will it know what c is in a seperate class??

Comment: Your are getting c from populateFrom(Cursor c, meetingHelper helper)

Comment: So look at the function which is calling populateForm.That function is not sending cursor properly

Comment: Its something wrong when i debug. i emailed the apk file to myself it works like a charm. its something about when i debug on this test phone.

Answer (score 0):

`helper.getType(c)` must be returning null. Where is the code for `meetingHelper`? Are the underlying `Cursor` instances on the regular and on the xlarge (which I'm assuming are 2 different databases) identical? You must have a null coming back from the Cursor for whichever row, or your `getType` method is doing something wrong.

Comment: No its all 1 database. When i run it on my tablet it works. when i run it on my smaller screen cell phone it forcec closes when i get to the list above

Comment: Is the data in both databases EXACTLY the same?

Comment: I only have one database. I have two different layouts xml for each screen size. It runs on layout-xlarge-land and portrait. but on regular layout it force closes

Comment: Ah, there is some confusion. I know you have 2 databases. I'm asking: is the data INSIDE the database on the tablet the exact same number of rows and exact same values as the data on the phone? I think that a particular row on the phone has a NULL in one of the columns and that is causing the `helper.getType` call to return NULL, which is what is causing the NullPointerException (this is why the `if` statement is crashing).

Comment: That cant be true, because it works when i block out the if(helper.getType() statement.

Comment: Ah, when you comment out the `if` statement, it is no longer calling `getType` so it no longer crashes: that is why it works. When you don't comment it out, then `getType` is returning NULL (because `c.getString(7)` is NULL). Perhaps you should put this line `android.util.Log.v(c.getString(7));` before the `return` statement and see what that prints out.

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor is null - this happens if there are no results returned from the database query.

You should check if the cursor is null before you operate on it.  Code change below:

```
meetingHolder(View row){
    mtitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mtitle);
    maddress = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
    Icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Micon);

}
void populateFrom(Cursor c, meetingHelper helper){
    if (c != null) {
         mtitle.setText(helper.getMettingTitle(c));
         maddress.setText(helper.getAddress(c));

         if(helper.getType(c).equals("completed")){
             Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.completed);

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That still didnt work. maybe its something going on with the debugging on the phone

Comment: When i emailed myself the apk it worked. it something wrong when i debug on my phone. Thanks for your response though.